# how to access images of movieDB API using React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am making a movie search application where you type in the name of a movie and it returns information of the movie. I have it set up so that I can already access all the information of the API and return it as the element I want. However, I cannot access the `poster_path` in the API. I would like for this to return as an image on the screen. Here is a screenshot of the API search in the browser.[image]

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    popularity: "",
    poster: "", //Problem
  }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = '***********************';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

        const popularity = res.data['results'][0]['popularity']
        this.setState({ popularity });

        const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']//Problem
        this.setState({ poster });//Problem

      })
        }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
    <h1>{this.state.popularity}</h1>
    <img src={this.state.poster} />//Problem
    </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `tmdb` specific configuration. You have to concat the `poster_path` with the URL `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p` with the size of the image you want and pass it as src. See tmdb API [docs](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/configuration/get-api-configuration) for reference.

For example for `poster_path` `/udDclJoHjfjb8Ekgsd4FDteOkCU.jpg`, the image URL would be https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/udDclJoHjfjb8Ekgsd4FDteOkCU.jpg.

So in your code, you can to do something like this

```
const baseImgUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p"
const size = "w500"

const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']
this.setState({ poster });

return (
  // ....
  <img src={`${baseImgUrl}/${size}${this.state.poster}`} />
)
```